# quick-ng-repeat does not update view

Tags: angularjs, performance

I use **quick-ng-repeat** [Quick-ng-repeat](http://allaud.github.io/quick-ng-repeat/) for my list to iterate because it is a huge list and I would improve performance.

Now I recognized that if I change the model, the view is not updated with this code:

```
<span quick-ng-repeat="item in collection track by $index" quick-repeat-list="items">
 {{ item }}
</span>
```

With this code

```
<span ng-repeat="item in collection track by $index">
 {{ item }}
</span>
```

every works fine.
Does anyone have any idee why this happens?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

quick-ng-repeat does not implement deep watch just like ng-repeat, it implement one way binding approach. So if your model changes frequently, don't use it.

In Angular 1.2 a new addition was made to the syntax of ngRepeat: the amazingly awesome track by clause. It allows you to specify your own key for ngRepeat to identify objects by, instead of just generating unique IDs.

This means that you can change the above to be ng-repeat="task in tasks track by task.id" and since the ID would be the same in both your original tasks and the updated ones from the server – ngRepeat will know not to recreate the DOM elements and reuse them

Answer (score 1):

The Quick ng-repeat is doing one way binding ,it something similar to what we do in angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item.name}}</div>
```

This does not create unnecessary watches.

Answer (score 1):

I think Quick-ng-repeat use Single binding same as in angular 1.4 like (::).Single binding mean it will be create a watcher for your repeat that why it will not effect when object is change.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in ::objList">{{obj.name}}</div>
```